# .htaccess neat urls, if the $_GET data has a space it redirects to 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im using .htaccess to turn my url from

```
www.mysite.com/profile.php?name=name
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/name/name
```

But I've struck a problem in which if a name has a space instead of showing the user data it takes me to my 404 page.. Ive encoded the names, so that if theres a space it replaces it with %20 but its still not working..
Names without a space work just fine

Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?name=$1
```

Comment: Show your rewrite rules.

Comment: Depending on your rules for validating a name, you may want to keep that regular expression. Another option is to create a URL-safe version of name to use in URLs. This can be done by running the name through a function that strips spaces and other special characters not allowed in URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your Rewrite rules. You have a regular expression that says "one or more letters or numbers":

[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+

A whitespace is not one of those. That is why it's not matching. Add \s to the regex:

[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression for the rewrite doesn't account for spaces or encoded characters.  Instead, it is only matching letters, numbers, underscore or dash.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule /(.+) /profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Based on your example, I would expect the rule to look more like:

```
RewriteRule /name/(.+) /profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will match the entire GET path and pass it as $1 to the rewrite.  If you need to append additional query string arguments, see the `QSA` flag.

Comment: This will match slashes - be careful.

Comment: @AlexWeinstein Fair point...  I couldn't tell exactly what the OP was trying to match since the original rewrite rules didn't seem to match the example.

Comment: This gave me an infinite loop :( Thanks for the help though!